# Linux unzip file from script without outputting the unzipped file names

Tags: command-line, scripts, zip, unzip

I unzipped a file from a script with "unzip filename.zip" and in the terminal I see all the unzipped file names. I would like to unzip the file without printing those names so that I have a clean terminal interface.

Comment: `man unzip` is your friend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `MODIFIERS` section of `man unzip`:

> ```
> -q     perform  operations  quietly  (-qq  = even quieter).  Ordinarily
>        unzip prints the names of the files it's extracting or  testing,
>        the extraction methods, any file or zipfile comments that may be
>        stored in the archive, and possibly a summary when finished with
>        each  archive.   The -q[q] options suppress the printing of some
>        or all of these messages.
> ```

So

```
unzip -q filename.zip
```

Comment: Does that work also with move and copy? When I moved my files to another directories it displayed the whole process in the terminal just like it did with zip

Comment: @Jim6834 are you referring to the standard `mv` and `cp` commands? if so, then AFAIK they don't report successful operations by default (they use `-v` to increase the verbosity, rather than `-q` to decrease it). Or are you moving/copying files some other way?

Comment: @Jim6834 If you want something that works with practically anything: `your command 2>/dev/null`.